# Is there a way to have a numpy array as the default in luigi.Parameter?

Tags: python, numpy, luigi

I am building a `luigi` task, and I want to have a `numpy` array as the default to one of the input parameters:

```
import numpy as np
import luigi

class MyLuigiTask(luigi.Task):
    my_array = luigi.Parameter(default=np.array([2, 3]))
```

Then at runtime I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dalyag/MyModule/my_nodule.py", line 124, in <module>
    execution_summary = luigi.build([MyLuigiTask()],
  File "/home/dalyag/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/task_register.py", line 88, in __call__
    param_values = cls.get_param_values(params, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/dalyag/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/task.py", line 419, in get_param_values
    if not param_obj.has_task_value(task_family, param_name):
  File "/home/dalyag/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/parameter.py", line 231, in has_task_value
    return self._get_value(task_name, param_name) != _no_value
  File "/home/dalyag/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/parameter.py", line 206, in _get_value
    if value != _no_value:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Which, to the best of my understanding, is caused by the `Parameter` class trying to understand whether a default value exists.

Since the default holds more than value (it holds a `numpy` array on values), it cannot discern that.

I tried using `ListParameter` instead, but get the same error.

The solution I implemented so far is to use a list as the default, and later turn it into an array, but it is not that elegant...

```
class MyLuigiTask(luigi.Task):
    my_array = luigi.ListParameter(default=[2, 3])
```

If anyone has a solution I would love to hear :)

Thanks!

---

p.s. I am using `Python3.6.7` and `luigi==2.8.9`.

Comment: Mmm I don't know Luigi, but numpy sort of breaks (on purpose) the expected semantics of the comparison operators to perform *elementwise* comparisons, returning an array of booleans instead of a boolean, as Luigi reasonably expects

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for your input :) This was also my observation. Maybe a clarification is needed then - what I am looking for in fact is a "luigi" way to have numpy arrays as default, either as a builtin class like `ListParameter` or some other hack :)

Comment: `np.array([1,2]) is None` produces a scalar False, but the `!= _no_value` will be an array regardless of what `_no_value` is (but what is it?).  If there aren't many  `luigi` coders hanging around, you may have to dig into its code yourself.  `numpy` just helps us identify the problem, not a solution.

Comment: @hpaulj: It’s plainly a bug to use `!=` rather than `is not` to recognize a special *object* (here, a default argument).

Comment: Looks like `_no_value = object()` - that is a plain base Python object.  Else where the docs say the `default` `This should match the type of the Parameter`.  Without more knowledge about this `parameter` class, and the purpose of the `default` I can't say what is reasonable.  It's quite likely that this package was written without any thought to making it `numpy` compatible.  In general I think `numpy` arrays should be used for `data`, not `parameters`.

Answer (score 2):

Luigi task parameters are not just parameters to a function  - they are meant to be read from the command line (as in `luigi --module my_tasks MyLuigiTask --my_array '[2,3]'` so they are limited to basic types and they have to be converted anyway if you need more specialized types (like numpy array in your example)

Comment: Thanks! This makes total sense... Thank you for your input, I can now feel conformable with my not-so-elegant code ;)